# Build Hugin Project - boost not found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

When I build hugin project with Cmake, I meet a problem:

```
Boost is not found.  Bad BOOST_ROOT? On windows, try editing Boost_root_suffix
 -- Current HG revision is 
Found wxWidgets: TRUE
Found TIFF: D:/wendang/Hugin/huginbase/tiff-3.8.2/libtiff
Found JPEG: D:/wendang/Hugin/huginbase/wxWidgets-2.8.10/src/jpeg
Found PNG: D:/wendang/Hugin/huginbase/wxWidgets-2.8.10/src/png
Found EXIV2: D:/wendang/Hugin/huginbase/exiv2-0.18.1/msvc/include
GLUT Found
libpano13 version: 2.9.12 major 2 minor 9 patch 12
```

The error is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:274 (MESSAGE):
  Boost not found.  Bad BOOST_ROOT? On windows, try editing Boost_root_suffix
```

I can't solve the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Where's your Boost installation? Did you try what the error suggests and add a variable `Boost_root_suffix` to your CMake script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Boost library? If you not, you can check [here](http://www.boost.org/) for details.